# XAML Vector to Illustrator or similar

Tags: silverlight, xaml, vector-graphics, adobe-illustrator

I can easily enough go from Adobe Illustrator and make a XAML file via the XPS Virtual Printer, but is there any way to import Vector graphics defined in XAML into Adobe Illustrator to continue working on it?

Cheers

```
Nik
```

Answer (score 8):

You could try using [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/) to convert your XAML into a format Illustrator understands. It support XAML import and export.

Comment: Tried Inkscape.  Works fine.  Had to save as EMF from Inscape.  Illustrator CS4 wouldn't read any other format it saved in.

Answer (score 0):

Export your drawing in Expression Designer as PDF or PSD and open it in Illustrator