# Converting Xaml Paths to AI or an open standard vector path

Tags: xaml, graphics, fireworks

I have a xaml path that needs to be converted to AI or some other form of vector graphics such as a fireworks format where the paths can be edited.

This is the xaml:

```
<Canvas xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" x:Name="Layer_1" Width="80" Height="50" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0">
<Path Width="105.125" Height="146.054" Canvas.Left="1.90355" Canvas.Top="14.8609" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 1.90355,33.7685L 10.6186,30.9619L 11.9803,29.6325L 9.80157,29.6325L 9.6654,28.5985L 10.0739,28.1553L 9.39305,27.4168L 10.6186,25.6442L 13.4782,24.7579L 14.4314,24.6102L 17.5634,22.6899L 14.5676,22.5421L 14.1591,21.6558L 16.3379,20.7696L 17.2911,20.7696L 17.6996,21.2127L 19.0613,20.7696L 18.9251,19.2924L 18.9251,18.1107L 21.7848,18.2584L 24.2359,16.7812L 26.8232,16.1904L 30.0913,15.7472L 32.2701,15.7472L 35.6744,17.2244L 37.717,17.2244L 39.6234,17.0767L 40.5766,18.1107L 41.3937,18.5538L 43.9809,17.5198L 49.1555,16.7812L 50.5172,17.0767L 51.1981,17.8152L 52.2875,17.5198L 54.6024,17.5198L 56.1003,17.8152L 56.7812,17.963L 57.5982,18.7015L 56.7812,19.1447L 58.2791,18.8493L 60.4578,19.4401L 60.3217,19.8833L 62.9089,19.5878L 64.8154,18.8493L 70.2623,19.1447L 73.1219,18.2584L 73.1219,17.3721L 72.3049,16.6335L 73.2581,15.5995L 75.0283,14.8609L 75.8454,16.1904L 75.0283,17.6675L 75.3007,18.1107L 76.7986,17.6675L 76.6624,18.7015L 77.2071,19.1447L 80.0667,16.4858L 81.837,17.5198L 80.6114,18.997L 80.3391,20.4741L 76.5262,21.2127L 72.9857,22.9853L 66.7218,26.3828L 64.9515,28.5985L 64.9515,29.9279L 66.858,30.3711L 69.1729,32.4391L 72.0325,32.8822L 71.4878,35.098L 71.3517,37.166L 73.1219,37.3137L 73.6666,35.2457L 74.0751,33.6208L 77.0709,32.8822L 77.8879,30.9619L 78.1603,29.0416L 78.1603,28.4508L 80.4752,25.9396L 81.5646,25.0533L 84.2881,25.7919L 85.2413,28.3031L 85.5136,29.3371L 86.3307,29.4848L 87.42,28.5985L 88.3733,27.4168L 89.1903,27.1213L 89.5988,29.4848L 89.5988,31.4051L 89.5988,32.7345L 90.8244,32.7345L 92.4584,33.1777L 91.9137,34.3594L 93.4116,35.098L 92.4584,36.8706L 90.1435,37.3137L 84.9689,38.7909L 82.7902,39.0863L 79.1135,41.0066L 77.3433,42.4838L 81.2923,40.7112L 83.1987,40.1203L 84.4242,40.8589L 82.5178,41.8929L 83.471,43.0746L 85.5136,44.4041L 86.603,44.5518L 81.837,46.4721L 80.6114,46.7675L 81.837,44.8472L 80.0667,44.9949L 78.1603,46.4721L 76.2539,47.3584L 75.573,48.6878L 73.9389,49.5741L 72.7134,49.5741L 72.3049,51.199L 70.807,51.7899L 70.5346,52.9716L 69.3091,53.7102L 69.1729,55.4827L 68.9006,56.9599L 67.675,57.6985L 65.3601,59.0279L 64.4069,60.8005C 62.7466,61.7702 61.9053,63.8389 62.3643,65.8228L 63.4536,68.4817L 62.5004,68.9249L 61.5472,68.0386L 61.0025,65.6751L 60.594,64.0503L 60.1855,63.3117L 59.2323,62.7208L 58.5514,62.7208L 57.7344,62.7208L 55.828,62.8685L 54.8748,62.7208L 53.9216,63.6071L 52.9683,63.6071L 52.696,62.4254L 50.5172,63.4594L 49.4279,64.198L 46.8406,65.6751L 46.2959,67.0046L 46.2959,69.9589L 45.7512,73.5041L 47.3853,76.7538L 49.9725,76.9015L 52.1513,75.7198L 52.9683,74.5381L 53.6492,72.9132L 55.1471,72.9132L 55.828,73.2086L 54.8748,75.1289L 54.1939,77.3447L 53.6492,78.6741L 53.513,79.8558L 55.0109,79.8558L 58.2791,79.5604L 59.3685,80.299L 58.9599,81.7761L 58.2791,83.6964L 58.0067,85.469L 58.9599,87.3893L 60.4578,87.8325L 61.8196,87.9802L 63.0451,87.0939L 64.543,87.0939L 65.0877,88.2756L 65.2239,88.7188L 66.3133,86.9462L 68.492,85.1736L 69.8538,83.8442L 70.2623,85.3213L 69.8538,87.3893L 70.9431,87.537L 71.7602,86.0599L 72.3049,84.5827L 74.0751,85.469L 75.573,85.7645L 78.1603,85.9122L 79.6582,86.3553L 81.0199,88.2756L 81.4284,88.7188L 83.3349,89.7528L 83.7434,89.9005L 85.3775,90.4914L 86.7392,91.3777L 88.2371,91.5254L 90.0073,93.5934L 91.6414,96.2523L 91.0967,97.7294L 92.3223,98.1726L 95.7266,99.9452L 99.4033,101.422L 102.263,101.865L 104.033,103.638L 105.667,104.377L 106.893,105.115L 107.029,106.592L 106.62,108.956L 105.531,110.581L 104.305,111.615L 103.08,113.535L 102.671,116.489L 103.08,119.444L 103.488,121.069L 102.535,122.841L 102.127,123.58L 101.582,125.057L 99.6756,125.648L 97.4968,126.386L 96.4074,126.977L 95.9989,127.42L 95.8628,129.488L 96.1351,131.556L 95.9989,132.295L 94.9096,133.033L 93.8202,134.067L 93.684,135.692L 93.0031,137.17L 92.7308,138.647L 90.9605,138.794L 90.1435,138.794L 90.1435,139.681L 90.552,142.044L 90.0073,143.521L 88.6456,144.112L 87.1477,144.112L 87.0115,146.623L 86.3307,147.066L 85.3775,147.066L 85.9902,148.544L 85.7519,149.43L 85.7179,150.132L 85.1732,150.316L 85.037,151.535L 85.6158,151.793L 86.6371,152.089L 86.8073,152.864L 86.4328,154.046L 86.2966,155.339L 86.1945,156.668L 86.3988,157.333L 87.1477,158.367L 88.203,159.253L 89.1903,159.955L 89.8371,160.361L 89.8712,160.841L 88.6116,160.915L 87.4541,160.287L 86.0583,159.364L 85.1732,158.514L 84.3902,158.034L 82.9264,157.111L 81.3263,154.932L 79.4199,151.498L 78.739,148.765L 78.4326,146.549L 77.7518,146.143L 76.6057,144.161L 75.9702,141.306L 75.8794,136.086L 75.3347,134.806L 74.8808,132.738L 74.6992,130.178L 74.6992,125.746L 74.4269,123.58L 73.973,120.921L 73.7914,119.641L 71.7034,117.966L 69.5247,117.08L 67.2551,115.505L 66.2565,112.255L 64.0778,108.907L 63.5331,107.528L 62.3529,105.854L 61.5359,105.066L 61.1727,103.786L 62.0806,102.21L 62.4437,102.013L 62.1714,100.93L 61.4451,98.1726L 62.4437,96.5969L 63.7146,95.2183L 64.6225,93.2487L 64.1686,90.1959L 63.4423,88.2264L 62.3529,88.3249L 61.899,89.7035L 59.811,89.3096L 58.0862,88.4233L 56.3613,86.0599L 55.9982,84.6812L 55.5443,83.4995L 54.5457,83.0071L 52.0038,82.3178L 51.0052,81.7269L 49.1895,80.1513L 47.737,80.1513L 45.1044,79.7574L 41.2915,78.0832L 40.1114,77.2954L 37.8418,75.3259L 37.5695,73.3563L 37.2971,71.7807L 35.0276,67.5462L 32.9396,63.5086L 32.1226,61.736L 30.9424,60.9482L 31.0332,63.5086L 32.3949,66.4629L 33.3935,69.4173L 34.1198,71.6822L 33.3027,71.0914L 31.6687,67.6447L 30.1254,65.0843L 29.1268,60.5543L 29.1268,59.0772L 28.0374,58.0924L 26.6757,56.8122L 26.6757,53.5624L 26.3125,51.6914L 26.131,50.1157L 27.1296,48.3432L 29.3991,44.8965L 30.7608,43.1239L 30.7608,40.3665L 30.3977,38.4954L 30.8516,37.1168L 31.124,34.5564L 29.853,31.996L 29.3991,30.0264L 29.2176,28.5493L 27.8558,27.2691L 24.043,26.6782L 22.8628,27.7614L 20.3209,28.3523L 19.1408,28.3523L 20.0486,27.2691L 17.5975,28.3523L 15.1464,29.9279L 11.0612,31.5036L 7.33913,32.8822L 1.90355,33.7685 Z "/>
<Path Width="23.4217" Height="6.35178" Canvas.Left="81.6469" Canvas.Top="4.61105" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 81.6469,6.90065L 84.5066,9.04252L 82.6682,9.41182L 82.464,10.1504L 85.664,10.6674L 88.2513,10.372L 89.2726,10.9628L 91.5195,9.41182L 95.6046,7.93466L 98.0558,6.82679L 101.732,6.08821L 104.728,5.27578L 105.069,4.75877L 93.2216,4.61105L 92.4727,4.90648L 91.7237,5.27578L 89.2045,5.27578L 86.6853,5.49735L 87.6385,6.90065L 86.8215,6.90065L 85.4598,6.08821L 83.0087,6.53136L 81.6469,6.90065 Z "/>
<Path Width="38.4007" Height="22.6744" Canvas.Left="96.2855" Canvas.Top="3.87248" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 96.3536,8.74709L 99.5537,9.19024L 98.1919,9.63339L 96.8983,9.70724L 96.6259,10.372L 102.754,10.6674L 103.503,12.5877L 104.32,14.8034L 105.273,15.6897L 105.205,17.3146L 104.047,18.127L 104.047,19.7519L 103.298,19.6781L 102.89,20.6382L 103.026,22.1892L 102.618,23.2971L 102.345,23.888L 103.094,25.7344L 103.979,26.3991L 104.932,26.3253L 105.75,26.5468L 107.928,24.3311L 108.95,23.8141L 110.107,23.2971L 110.652,21.9676L 111.06,21.2291L 113.648,21.0075L 116.099,20.2689L 117.256,19.5303L 119.775,18.3486L 122.295,17.8316L 123.384,17.6839L 123.929,16.5022L 122.907,16.3545L 122.839,15.2466L 124.405,15.0989L 125.154,15.9852L 126.175,15.3943L 124.609,13.1786L 125.903,12.8093L 127.265,11.7014L 129.171,9.48567L 128.627,8.45166L 130.941,7.19608L 133.529,5.79278L 134.686,5.42349L 128.763,5.71892L 127.129,4.5372L 123.452,4.02019L 121.409,3.87248L 119.775,4.5372L 118.141,4.75877L 114.873,5.20192L 111.605,5.57121L 108.745,5.79278L 106.226,5.57121L 105.341,6.01435L 102.345,6.4575L 101.46,6.4575L 101.46,7.56537L 100.983,7.8608L 97.9196,8.00851L 96.2855,8.15623L 96.3536,8.74709 Z "/>
<Path Width="162.454" Height="129.694" Canvas.Left="116.156" Canvas.Top="8.45153" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 147.544,54.2434L 146.386,53.2832L 145.161,52.8401L 144.888,52.3231L 147.067,52.2492L 148.361,51.6584L 148.02,50.1074L 146.863,49.3688L 144.616,48.1132L 143.322,46.7838L 141.892,45.3066L 140.667,45.2327L 139.986,46.119L 139.305,46.4883L 138.08,46.4883L 137.399,45.9713L 136.786,46.119L 136.514,47.2269L 135.969,48.1132L 134.743,48.7041L 133.722,49.2949L 133.245,50.2551L 133.245,51.8061L 133.314,52.2492L 132.428,52.9878L 131.475,53.431L 130.794,53.8741L 129.501,53.8741L 128.752,53.948L 128.139,54.8343L 128.071,54.982L 127.254,54.3172L 126.437,54.0218L 125.824,53.948L 125.143,53.8741L 125.007,53.2832L 124.939,52.1015L 124.735,51.3629L 125.211,49.8858L 125.416,47.8178L 125.211,46.3406L 125.756,46.0452L 126.164,45.6759L 127.594,46.3406L 129.365,46.3406L 130.999,46.2667L 132.428,46.0452L 132.837,44.051L 131.611,41.9091L 130.931,41.0967L 129.365,40.949L 129.773,40.2104L 131.271,39.9888L 132.292,39.9888L 132.292,39.6195L 131.816,38.6594L 133.45,38.7332L 133.518,39.1764L 134.471,38.2901L 136.65,36.8129L 137.126,36.1482L 139.305,35.1881L 138.965,34.2279L 139.918,34.3018L 140.395,33.4893L 141.007,34.1541L 141.416,33.4155L 140.803,31.8645L 141.212,30.3873L 141.892,29.5749L 142.846,29.4272L 142.233,30.8305L 142.573,32.6769L 143.05,33.6371L 144.48,33.5632L 146.318,33.0462L 147.816,33.1939L 148.837,33.0462L 149.927,32.7508L 150.539,32.603L 151.288,32.086L 151.629,31.1259L 151.765,30.018L 152.582,29.6487L 153.535,30.3873L 154.012,30.3873L 154.08,29.6487L 154.012,29.0579L 153.399,28.467L 153.876,27.433L 154.897,27.2853L 156.259,27.0637L 157.484,26.7683L 155.578,26.2513L 154.557,26.5467L 152.582,27.1376L 151.901,26.399L 151.016,25.5865L 151.22,24.4048L 150.948,23.0754L 152.991,22.1891L 153.739,21.3028L 153.195,20.4904L 151.629,20.3426L 150.88,20.8596L 150.744,22.1152L 150.131,22.7061L 149.382,23.1492L 148.565,23.9617L 147.748,24.9218L 147.884,25.7343L 148.973,26.5467L 149.382,27.433L 149.246,27.95L 147.884,28.6147L 147.544,29.5749L 147.476,30.9043L 147.339,31.7168L 146.318,31.7906L 145.297,31.7168L 144.684,31.1259L 144.139,30.6827L 143.867,29.8703L 143.458,28.984L 142.709,27.95L 142.437,27.7284L 141.143,28.1716L 140.735,28.9102L 139.646,29.2056L 138.76,29.1317L 138.08,27.95L 138.012,26.8421L 137.671,25.8081L 138.148,24.4787L 140.054,23.6662L 141.824,22.4845L 146.046,18.1269L 145.365,17.6099L 145.637,16.7975L 147.067,16.8713L 150.539,15.6157L 152.037,15.3203L 155.646,15.0987L 159.05,16.3543L 165.178,18.053L 165.586,18.7916L 163.816,19.8256L 160.957,19.4564L 158.097,18.7178L 159.254,19.6779L 160.752,19.7518L 160.752,21.9675L 163.952,22.2629L 163.34,21.7459L 162.591,21.3767L 162.591,20.7858L 164.225,21.5982L 165.246,21.6721L 165.518,21.4505L 165.246,20.2688L 167.561,19.6779L 167.221,18.6439L 166.948,16.4282L 169.127,16.9452L 168.787,18.6439L 173.212,16.8713L 177.502,17.2406L 180.089,17.1668L 177.229,15.6157L 180.77,15.3203L 182.131,17.536L 185.536,17.536L 183.357,15.9112L 183.357,13.8432L 185.263,12.8091L 186.761,15.468L 188.055,18.5701L 187.374,19.5302L 190.37,19.4564L 189.485,16.7975L 191.255,16.8713L 188.464,15.985L 187.578,14.2863L 188.532,13.917L 189.212,14.7294L 188.259,13.6954L 189.893,13.4L 191.323,13.4L 190.574,12.4399L 192.14,11.6274L 194.727,11.9967L 194.591,10.3718L 202.285,8.59925L 205.008,8.45153L 211.136,9.33783L 210.728,10.8888L 208.753,11.6274L 208.753,12.8091L 214.132,11.4797L 221.077,12.4399L 220.941,11.7013L 224.413,12.4399L 226.66,13.5477L 228.294,14.5817L 229.247,15.3942L 229.043,13.4L 231.358,13.9909L 234.626,13.6954L 233.469,12.8091L 235.715,12.6614L 240.209,13.5477L 251.511,14.951L 253.418,15.985L 256.958,15.468L 258.661,16.4282L 260.09,16.7975L 258.797,15.0987L 268.397,16.5759L 276.976,18.4223L 278.61,20.2688L 277.725,21.4505L 273.163,20.2688L 270.44,19.5302L 271.393,20.6381L 269.759,20.9335L 272.482,21.6721L 274.797,22.7061L 274.933,23.0754L 272.754,23.297L 271.529,23.9617L 270.712,25.882L 267.444,25.8081L 266.354,26.0297L 267.103,27.433L 270.099,30.1657L 270.576,32.6769L 269.963,36.0005L 266.286,35.9266L 263.971,32.086L 262.133,27.5807L 264.584,23.814L 262.678,23.1492L 263.018,25.9558L 260.431,25.6604L 259.001,24.4048L 260.022,26.7683L 256.822,27.1376L 253.622,26.9898L 250.014,27.0637L 249.333,27.5807L 248.788,29.0579L 248.72,30.9043L 248.039,32.1599C 249.04,32.7244 250.122,33.099 251.239,33.2678L 254.984,34.1541L 255.937,35.0404L 256.618,38.9548L 256.005,42.8693L 256.005,45.0112L 254.303,46.1929L 251.852,45.7497L 252.533,47.4485L 251.443,49.6642L 252.056,51.2891L 254.643,53.2832L 254.916,55.4251L 253.418,55.8683L 252.329,56.9023L 252.465,54.9081L 250.694,53.7264L 250.967,53.0617L 248.243,51.9538L 249.06,49.9596L 246.065,50.2551L 244.022,50.6982L 242.796,52.3969L 247.29,53.431L 247.426,55.1297L 247.358,56.2376L 248.992,58.2317L 249.401,60.2997L 249.605,62.737L 249.265,64.5835L 248.584,67.5378L 246.882,70.1228L 244.09,71.083L 242.116,71.9693L 239.392,72.1908L 237.486,72.634L 236.056,75.219L 238.575,78.3949C 239.496,79.3935 240.235,80.5711 240.754,81.8662L 240.754,82.9741L 240.277,85.1898L 238.847,86.0023L 237.554,87.2578L 236.669,85.4853L 235.239,83.3434L 233.605,83.048L 232.039,82.2355L 232.175,85.1898L 232.515,86.8147L 235.307,91.4677L 236.396,93.5358L 237.009,95.2345L 235.579,95.8992L 233.877,94.7914L 232.924,91.837L 231.698,88.8827L 230.337,88.0703L 230.337,85.2637L 231.018,83.1957L 229.315,80.6106L 229.315,78.4688L 227.409,76.253L 227.205,77.6563L 226.115,77.8779L 224.89,73.3726L 222.643,71.6L 221.826,71.4523L 219.511,72.1908L 216.992,72.5601L 216.515,75.6622L 214.336,78.0995L 212.294,79.7982L 211.953,82.6048L 212.089,85.633L 211.477,87.4794L 210.387,88.218L 208.753,86.9624L 207.255,82.9741L 205.485,78.6903L 203.851,73.7419L 203.715,71.5261L 203.374,72.9294L 202.421,74.0373L 200.991,71.9693L 200.174,71.6L 201.536,70.6398L 199.834,70.1228L 197.451,68.8672L 197.383,66.9469L 195.408,66.9469L 192.753,66.9469L 189.689,67.0208L 188.259,66.7992L 187.442,65.2482L 185.944,65.8391L 184.991,65.5436L 183.697,64.3619L 182.063,62.9586L 180.021,61.703L 178.863,61.6292L 180.021,64.8051L 180.838,65.9868L 181.791,66.5777L 182.2,66.8731L 182.88,67.0947L 183.561,68.4241L 184.378,69.3104L 187.17,67.6117L 187.306,67.3162L 189.349,69.3842L 191.391,70.566L 191.8,72.1908L 189.893,73.5203L 189.621,75.219L 188.668,76.4746L 186.08,77.1393L 181.927,80.5368L 179.748,81.3492L 176.208,82.8264L 175.936,81.4969L 176.14,80.0936L 176.072,78.6165L 175.187,77.287L 174.71,76.0315L 173.825,75.219L 172.327,74.0373L 171.714,71.7477L 171.17,70.1228L 170.148,68.2025L 168.446,65.9129L 167.561,64.4358L 166.608,64.0665L 165.246,63.5495L 164.974,63.0325L 164.361,63.1802L 166.54,66.7254L 167.629,69.2365L 168.31,72.3386L 170.012,76.5485L 172.327,81.1276L 175.663,83.4911L 176.616,84.5251L 178.863,85.633L 183.085,84.1558L 182.812,86.0023L 181.655,91.3939L 179.953,94.4221L 178.114,95.4561L 176.276,97.8934L 174.029,100.257L 172.872,102.62L 172.327,104.467L 172.395,106.535L 172.94,108.603L 173.212,112.296L 173.893,116.358L 171.033,118.647L 168.718,119.903L 167.765,123.744L 167.97,127.289L 166.608,128.323L 165.859,130.022L 163.68,132.976L 162.182,135.339L 160.071,136.816L 157.212,137.85L 152.991,138.146L 151.493,137.924L 151.356,136.078L 151.629,135.192L 151.765,134.231L 149.586,130.465L 148.565,126.55L 148.361,123.965L 147.68,122.193L 146.658,120.494L 145.773,118.574L 145.297,117.54L 146.863,114.216L 147.544,111.114L 147.544,108.603L 145.841,104.984L 144.684,102.99L 143.39,100.478L 142.369,99.149L 141.892,98.632L 142.097,96.6378L 142.709,94.3482L 142.165,92.5756L 140.463,91.9848L 139.237,92.5756L 138.42,92.5756L 137.263,91.3939L 135.765,90.286L 133.79,91.0246L 130.59,92.1325L 127.186,92.7233L 125.075,92.7233L 122.692,90.5076L 121.603,89.3997L 119.969,88.2919L 119.492,86.667L 118.675,85.0421L 117.109,83.4172L 116.292,81.6447L 116.156,79.2812L 117.109,77.4348L 117.381,75.4406L 116.7,73.3726L 116.905,71.9693L 118.062,68.8672L 119.492,66.5038L 122.42,63.9188L 123.85,63.1802L 124.122,60.669L 125.62,58.2317L 127.458,56.1637L 128.343,55.6467L 131.203,56.016L 135.833,55.0558L 139.509,54.2434L 141.961,54.1695L 143.186,55.2774L 142.846,56.3114L 142.846,57.4193L 143.254,58.3794L 144.48,58.8226L 146.999,59.4134L 148.837,59.7827L 149.654,61.186L 150.607,61.703L 152.514,61.2599L 152.582,59.7089L 154.284,59.4873L 157.552,60.5213L 160.003,60.8167L 163.612,60.8167L 164.769,60.8906L 166.063,60.0782L 166.335,58.3056L 167.561,56.2376L 167.221,54.6127L 164.906,54.465L 162.727,54.2434L 161.161,54.1695L 159.935,53.8002L 157.825,51.9538L 157.757,50.1074L 160.957,49.3688L 162.455,48.7779L 165.178,48.3348L 168.514,48.6302L 170.761,48.6302L 171.646,47.4485L 170.897,46.4145L 169.535,45.3066L 167.629,44.4942L 168.038,42.5L 168.65,41.1706L 165.723,41.7614L 164.157,42.8693L 164.838,43.9772L 164.293,44.4203L 163.612,43.9772L 162.999,42.9431L 161.637,42.6477L 158.982,43.3124L 159.05,45.0112L 159.459,46.8576L 160.616,48.7779L 160.276,49.1472L 157.484,48.3348L 155.85,48.5563L 154.829,50.1812L 154.965,51.8799L 154.761,52.6185L 152.786,51.8799L 151.629,49.8119L 151.765,48.4086L 150.539,47.0792L 148.293,45.6759L 146.522,44.4203L 145.501,43.7556L 145.569,44.7157L 146.25,46.4145L 147.271,47.5223L 148.701,48.4825L 149.79,49.6642L 150.403,50.3289L 149.314,50.1812L 149.654,50.9198L 149.178,52.0277L 148.429,53.0617L 147.544,54.2434 Z "/>
<Path Width="27.5069" Height="18.3167" Canvas.Left="227.908" Canvas.Top="90.237" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 227.908,91.7142L 231.585,95.9979L 233.491,100.577L 236.487,103.975L 239.21,106.633L 243.84,107.963L 249.968,108.554L 255.415,108.406C 255.249,107.597 254.709,106.94 253.987,106.669C 253.265,106.398 252.465,106.552 251.874,107.077L 247.244,107.077L 243.295,106.043L 238.938,103.827L 236.895,99.8385L 234.308,96.7365L 230.359,92.0096L 228.18,90.237L 227.908,91.7142 Z "/>
<Path Width="38.5369" Height="31.7589" Canvas.Left="241.253" Canvas.Top="111.065" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 259.364,114.906L 261.27,112.69L 263.449,111.36L 266.172,111.36L 267.67,112.247L 266.036,113.724L 265.9,114.758L 270.258,118.155L 271.892,115.644L 272.709,111.36L 274.07,111.065L 273.526,114.906L 275.977,118.008L 277.202,121.11L 278.292,123.473L 279.245,126.28L 279.79,128.643L 279.79,131.893L 275.432,136.177L 273.39,138.983L 271.347,140.756L 267.806,142.233L 265.628,142.824L 263.04,141.79L 262.768,139.574L 263.449,136.915L 262.632,136.177L 260.317,137.801L 259.228,136.029L 258.411,134.995L 255.415,134.699L 251.602,135.143L 249.832,137.211L 245.883,137.358L 242.478,137.801L 241.253,138.097L 242.887,134.847L 242.887,131.154L 242.342,128.348L 243.159,124.802L 246.427,122.734L 251.466,119.189L 253.645,117.86L 256.504,114.019L 258.547,113.724L 259.364,114.906 Z "/>
<Path Width="10.0768" Height="13.4421" Canvas.Left="240.98" Canvas.Top="89.3507" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 249.696,90.237L 250.376,91.271L 249.423,92.4528L 248.606,94.9639L 250.104,96.5888L 251.057,96.1456L 249.423,98.6568L 247.925,101.316L 246.427,102.793L 244.112,100.577L 241.934,100.282L 241.525,98.9522L 240.98,95.7025L 242.615,95.7025L 243.568,94.9639L 246.019,92.6005L 247.925,90.8279L 249.287,89.3507L 249.696,90.237 Z "/>
<Path Width="6.26395" Height="8.56752" Canvas.Left="251.193" Canvas.Top="95.4071" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 253.236,96.1456L 256.913,95.4071L 257.457,96.2934L 255.006,96.8842L 252.827,97.1797L 252.419,98.6568L 252.964,99.1L 255.279,98.5091L 254.87,100.577L 254.325,102.941L 254.053,103.384L 253.372,102.202L 252.01,103.236L 252.01,103.975L 251.33,102.793L 251.193,99.9863L 251.874,97.1797L 253.236,96.1456 Z "/>
<Path Width="18.5195" Height="11.6695" Canvas.Left="263.313" Canvas.Top="98.2137" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 264.675,101.463L 266.581,102.497L 270.258,103.827L 270.666,105.452L 269.304,105.747L 269.577,107.52L 272.164,107.52L 274.343,108.258L 276.113,106.633L 279.79,108.849L 280.334,109.44L 281.832,109.883L 278.836,106.486L 278.019,104.27L 277.611,102.497L 274.615,101.316L 271.483,99.8385L 268.76,99.6908L 267.943,101.316L 266.445,101.168L 265.355,100.134L 265.355,98.2137L 263.313,98.6568L 263.857,100.282L 264.811,100.873L 264.675,101.463 Z "/>
<Path Width="5.99161" Height="15.3624" Canvas.Left="177.05" Canvas.Top="112.071" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 177.595,117.389L 181.408,114.73L 181.952,112.071L 183.042,118.866L 181.135,125.957L 178.684,127.434L 177.05,127.434L 177.867,120.639L 177.595,117.389 Z "/>
<Path Width="6.35472" Height="9.50304" Canvas.Left="128.323" Canvas.Top="28.8581" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 129.503,28.8581L 131.41,29.252L 131.727,30.3352C 132.471,31.3126 133.04,32.4312 133.407,33.6342L 133.815,34.9144L 134.678,35.8992L 133.543,36.4901L 131.864,37.5733C 131.206,37.703 130.555,37.8673 129.912,38.0657L 128.323,38.3611L 129.912,35.9484L 130.184,34.2743L 129.685,32.6987L 128.595,31.0738L 128.459,29.9906L 129.503,28.8581 Z "/>
<Path Width="5.03841" Height="4.24235" Canvas.Left="124.283" Canvas.Top="32.6495" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 126.916,32.6987L 129.14,32.7479L 129.322,34.1759C 128.851,34.9051 128.351,35.6114 127.824,36.2931L 126.78,36.687C 126.089,36.9213 125.353,36.9552 124.646,36.7855L 124.283,35.8992L 125.327,33.7327L 126.462,32.6495L 127.097,32.6495L 126.916,32.6987 Z "/>
<Path Width="5.17456" Height="2.51117" Canvas.Left="62.3346" Canvas.Top="76.7917" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 64.0595,76.7917L 65.6028,76.841L 67.5092,78.7613L 64.2865,79.3029L 62.3346,77.5796L 64.0595,76.7917 Z "/>
<Path Width="10.1676" Height="3.29899" Canvas.Left="57.9771" Canvas.Top="71.3755" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 58.9303,72.2126L 60.4736,71.7694L 62.3346,72.1633L 64.6042,73.8374L 65.6936,74.576L 65.3758,74.6745L 67.373,74.6745L 68.1447,74.3298L 67.0099,73.9359L 64.9219,72.9511L 62.834,71.9171C 62.1733,71.61 61.4645,71.4428 60.746,71.4247L 58.7488,71.3755L 57.9771,72.311L 58.5218,72.6557L 59.2935,72.1141L 58.9303,72.2126 Z "/>
<Path Width="2.26955" Height="0.837059" Canvas.Left="74.698" Canvas.Top="76.4563" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 74.698,76.4563L 76.9675,76.7764C 76.483,76.965 75.9908,77.1293 75.4923,77.2687L 74.9249,77.2934L 74.698,76.4563 Z "/>
<Path Width="5.08378" Height="2.73273" Canvas.Left="69.0468" Canvas.Top="74.7083" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 70.8398,74.7083L 72.5646,75.2992C 73.1577,75.4297 73.7022,75.7465 74.1306,76.2101L 73.9717,76.9979C 73.0814,77.2521 72.1682,77.4007 71.2483,77.4411L 70.1362,77.3672L 69.0468,76.8748L 69.2738,75.9393L 70.1589,75.053L 70.8398,74.7083 Z "/>
```

Thanks

Comment: for anybody who was wondering, it's a picture of the world. neato

Comment: @Superman, ya. he designed it in design initially for exporting into blend but now we also need to put effects on it with fireworks while keeping the vectors.

Answer (score 0):

[Expression Blend](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Blend_Overview.aspx) will give you the ability to edit this, <s>and probably a few export options too</s>

[Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/) may be a better option (via [XAML Vector to Illustrator or similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606360))